# Delete some specific objects from a JSON file using python and then push the file to Elasticsearch Index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, boto, amazon-sqs

I am having a large json file which contains many object. I am trying to remove a certain number objects from this fetched file since they contains the public keys and stuff.. just for a ref i have something like this named download.json:

```
"osfamily": "Debian",
"sshrsakey":"Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2XXX",
"lsbmajdistrelease": "32",
"interfaces": "eth0,lo",
"physicalprocessorcount": 1,
"ec2_kernel_id": "pki-724545-724545",
```

My python script downloads the above json file from a SQS queue and pushes it the ES server as follows :

```
import os
import json
import uuid
import time
import boto.sqs
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage

sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")
q = sqs.get_queue("Nishantqueue")

#text_file = open('download.json', 'w')
m = q.read(visibility_timeout=15)
if m == None:
  print "No message!"
else:
  with open('download.json', 'w') as json_data:
    print m.get_body()
    json_data.write(m.get_body())

#    clean_data = json.load(json_data)  ##
#    for element in clean_data:         ##
#      del element['sshdsakey','sshrsakey'] 
#      json_data.write(clean_data) ## 

    json_data.close()
    q.delete_message(m)
    print "Push To ES"
    os.system('./push_to_ES.sh')
    print "Cleaning the temporary json file"
    os.remove('download.json')
    print "++++++ SUCCESSFUL RUN +++++++"
```

Now as you can see in the commented part, i am trying to delete the objects which i don't want and then write this to the download.json file and PUSH to ES . This commented part is not working the way i am thinking it should be and throws something like : `IOError: File not open for reading`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -2):

Open your file in read write mode.

Change:-

`with open('download.json', 'w') as json_data:`

to

`with open('download.json', 'r+') as json_data:`

-------------EDIT-----------------

why  not just do the following:-

```
clean_data = json.loads(m.get_body())
for element in clean_data:
  del element['sshdsakey','sshrsakey'] 

#write clean_data to download.json  
json_data.write(clean_data)

q.delete_message(m)
print "Push To ES"
os.system('./push_to_ES.sh')
print "Cleaning the temporary json file"
os.remove('download.json')
print "++++++ SUCCESSFUL RUN +++++++"
```

Comment: I don't have a file 'download.json' and i don't intend to read it before i append it with changed
File "read_msg_n_upload_to_ES.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open('download.json', 'r+') as json_data:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'download.json'

Comment: So why do you even write the data to `download.json` before pushing to ES. Just load the json received in `m.get_body()`-->delete what is not required and push the data.

Comment: yes , one good point... but if u see the  os.system('./push_to_ES.sh') , it calls up a curl command which pics up the download.json file to be sent to ES for indexing ...